# Bootstrap - 2 columns - make image full width on narrow screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the simple HTML below, images which are 640 pixels square appear in the left column, and other content appears in the right hand column.

Is there a way I can control the responsive nature of the HTML / CSS so that when the screen width is < 375 pixels, instead of the image getting smaller and smaller in the left hand column, the non-image content drops below the image and the image takes up the full width of the view screen?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <p>Something happened and something else happened and then it was the end.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <p>Nothing happens without blue cheese sandwiches being served first.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why not simply use a `css-grid` and media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a media query css enty like in the snippet below. That overwrites the bootstrap grid and replace it with a single columns grid if the screen size is 375px or smaller.

Highly recomemnd 480px as it is the highest portraite smartphone width.

```css
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 375px) {
    .container-fluid .row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <p>Something happened and something else happened and then it was the end.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <p>Nothing happens without blue cheese sandwiches being served first.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you very much indeed @tacoshy!